# Parsing element of a string array into a int

Tags: c#, string, parsing, integer

As the question says am trying to parse one of the elements of an string array into a int variable. although the code is right in terms of syntax, when I try to run it, I get the following error message.

> Error 1   Building content threw FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>      at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>      at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>      at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
>      at TileContent.Tiles.TileLayerProcessor.Process(XmlDocument input, ContentProcessorContext context) in C:\Users\Darren\Documents\Enders\TileContent\Tiles\TileLayerProcessor.cs:line 75

here is the code that is causing the problem below

```
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    string realLine = line.Trim();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                      continue;

                    string[] cells = realLine.Split(' ');

                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        int cellIndex = int.Parse(cells[x]);

                        layer.Layout[row, x] = cellIndex;
                    }
```

Comment: What is the value it chokes on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrsingly enough it was due to the tabbing I had done to the information which messed around with how it was being read in.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `cells[x]` cannot be parsed as an Int32.  Try debugging and inspecting `cells` after `string[] cells = realLine.Split(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to parse **one** of the elements, but your `for` loop is parsing **all** of the elements.

Provide us with the value of your `lines` variable, and then it would be much easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Additionally, you can use `int.TryParse()` to determine whether the value is in an `int` or not, without throwing an error..

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing the input, but assuming all the lines contain only valid int values, I would guess that there is more than one space separating the numbers in the line. In this case, the array returned by `Split` will contain some empty strings which cannot be converted to int. In this case use:

```
string[] cells = realLine.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use simple int parsing, be sure to provide IFormatProvider identifying the culture source. If you have numbers in culture-invariant form, use following code:

```
int cellIndex = int.Parse(cells[x], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It will probably not solve your problem now, but it is good to always pass CultureInfo parameter (this will work as a comment as well). BTW. If I were you, I will use TryParse() instead...